# How to check in one method if another method has been called?

Tags: python

Is there any way to execute method `c` when method `b` is called. I.e., if method `b` is called return something in method `c`. But how can I check if a method is called?

```
Class A:

    def __init__(self, arg1):
       return self.arg1
    def b(self, arg2):
       return self.arg2

    def c(self):
        # I want to know when method b is called 
        # so I can execute suite inside c.  
        # Is there anyway to do this
        # for example if method b is called return True, else if return something else.
```

Comment: Why not just add `self.c()` to `b`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to execute method c when method b is called?

Absolutely! You merely have to invoke c from within b.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1
    def b(self, arg2):
        self.c()
        return self.arg1 * 16 + arg2
    def c(self):
        print "c is being called!"

foo = A(23)
foo.b(42)
```

Now, every time you call `b`, method `c` will also be executed.

---

(by the way, `__init__` isn't allowed to return anything but `None`, and `self.arg2` doesn't exist, so I changed some of your methods)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to call `c` exactly when `b` is called?  Or whenever you call `c` check if `b` has been called?

If you want `c` to to be called when `b` is called just call it

```
def b(self, arg2):
    self.c()
    ### rest of b
```

If you just want to mark that `b` was called you can put a member variable in your class track, initialize it to `False` and set it to `True` when you call `b`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question right, but you can pass functions as arguments in Python. For example:

```
def square(x):
    return x ** 2

def cube(x):
    return x ** 3

def print_a_function_result(a_function, x):
    return a_function(x)

>>> print_a_function_result(square, 2):
>>> 4
>>> print_a_function_result(cube, 2):
>>> 8
>>> print_a_function_result(square, 3):
>>> 9
>>> print_a_function_result(cube, 3):
>>> 27
```

Comment: Yes, but in his case, it is a class, therefore, an instance of the class already knows about its methods, so no need to pass the method as arg.